# Password protect files/folders using cli

Tags: password

I have some important documents that I need to protect from anyone else having access to my machine.

The problem being the other persons have access to my machine via root account so changing the file permissions is not a option for me. I have seen apps like cryptkeeper but I was wondering can I password protect my files/folder by command line mode in ubuntu.

Comment: have a look on page 123: [Ubuntu Pocket Guide](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kHLlJzI6L20C&dq=ubuntu+pocket+guide&jtp=123#v=onepage&q=&f=false). It is for an older version of Ubuntu, but my work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If other users have root access to the system, then the only way that I can see to protect your files/folders is encryption and decryption.

Lot of answers are listed here (in AskUbuntu) about encrypt/decrypt , but I will show the simplest method, in my opinion.

**OpenSSL**

**Encrypt/Decrypt file**

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in file -out file.aes
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in file.aes -out file
```

**OpenSSL & Tar**

**Encrypt/Decrypt Folder**

```
tar -zcf - directory | openssl aes-256-cbc -out directory.tar.gz.aes
openssl aes-256-cbc -d  -in directory.tar.gz.aes | tar -xz -f -
```

Keep your decryption password out of the sight, and out of the System.

Comment: root will be able to gain access to the encrypted files as well -- for example, by installing a keylogger.

Comment: Then remove these files or folders from the PC completely :P Sorry but I don't know another way.

Comment: Nah. It is entirely sufficient to be the only user, keep the PC in a safe and cut off the Internet :-) Seriously, though, if you really want your data to be private, better not to put them on a computer with other users.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution. Say, you want to protect the folder "secret". Do the following:

```
mv secret secret.tmp
mkdir .secret.enc
mkdir secret
encfs ~/.secret.enc ~/secret
```

Now `encfs` will ask you about some options and a password. After that, `.secret.enc` will contain an encoded copy of anything you put to `~/secret`.

```
mv secret.tmp/* secret
rmdir secret.tmp
```

You can now treat `secret` as a normal folder: edit files, copy, move whatever. When you are done, do

```
fusermount -u ~/secret
```

The directory `secret` will now be empty, and the files will be, encrypted, in `.secret.enc`.

Note about the root: if anyone else has root permissions, you have no privacy, full stop. Even with encryption, root will always have the possibility to snoop on your terminal, hijack your passwords and keys, and gain access to your encrypted data.

**Another solution with the GUI**: put your files in a folder. Open the parent folder in Nautilus. Right click on your "secret" folder. Select "encrypt folder".