# How to password-protect an individual folder

Tags: security

I have to password-protect two folders: folder A is on my computer's hard drive, and folder B is on an external hard drive.

Regarding folder A: I have tried encrypting folder A using Cryptkeeper but, after doing so, the system does not allow me to unmount folder A because "you are not root", which I actually am.

Regarding folder B: I have tried using Cryptkeeper similarly to above, but the same error message popped up.

Could you suggest a way of password-protecting folders A and B? Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using TrueCrypt? It worked for me. Also this post may be of interest to you:

[Password protect files/folders using cli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316197/password-protect-files-folders-using-cli)