# how might I password protect and encrypt a folder in the Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, password, directory

Just wondering how to password protect and encrypt a folder in the Ubuntu 20.04 terminal (not OS)?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: thanks but I am looking for a command line only program

Comment: I don't have ubuntu desktop

Comment: does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/316197/password-protect-files-folders-using-cli

Comment: @User24601 yes this is a duplicate of that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password protect files/folders using cli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316197/password-protect-files-folders-using-cli)

Comment: I guess I am looking for something that only password protects not encrypts